# Handling tables in text files with VB6

Tags: database, csv, vb6

I want to make a VB6 executable that can handle a text file (or more) that have the following format.

```
X1 field | Y1 field | Z1 field \n
X2 field | Y2 field | Z2 field \n
....\n
....\n
Xn field | Yn field | Zn field.
```

It look's like a table from db or csv file and I would like to make a VB6 program that can search, edit and add all these fields. Is there any library or framework in VB6 to help me?

Comment: As far as adding them up, you're on your own as far as referencing the file: you can use the fileSystemObject http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186118 to handle this

Comment: @xQbert The FSO is rarely needed in VB6 itself. There are native versions that don't rely on the scripting engine components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A disconnected database.

```
Sub Randomise
    Randomize 
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "RandomNumber", 4 

        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            .AddNew
            .Fields("RandomNumber").value = Rnd() * 10000
            .Fields("Txt").value = Inp.readline
            .UpDate
        Loop
        .Sort = "RandomNumber"
        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value

            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to do with the data but you can use the following steps:

- Read in the file, either per line or the complete file at once
- Substract the data in the correct format
- write the data to your favorite database/control

For example, to read in the whole file at once, and show its fields into a MSFlexGrid you can do the following:

```
'1 form with:
'  1 MSFlexFrid control: name=MSFlexGrid1
'  1 Command button: name=Command1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim lngLine As Long, lngField As Long
  Dim intFile As Integer
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strData As String
  Dim strLine() As String, strField() As String
  'read the file
  strFile = "c:\temp\file.txt"
  intFile = FreeFile
  Open strFile For Input As #intFile
    strData = Input(LOF(intFile), #intFile)
  Close #intFile
  'split the file in separate lines
  strLine = Split(strData, "\n")
  'fill the grid with the data
  With MSFlexGrid1
    .Rows = UBound(strLine) + 1
    For lngLine = 0 To UBound(strLine)
      'put all fields from 1 line on 1 row in the grid
      strField = Split(strLine(lngLine), "|")
      If UBound(strField) > .Cols - 1 Then
        .Cols = UBound(strField) + 1
      End If
      For lngField = 0 To UBound(strField)
        .TextMatrix(lngLine, lngField) = strField(lngField)
      Next lngField
    Next lngLine
  End With 'MSFlexGrid1
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Dim sngWidth As Single, sngHeight As Single
  Dim sngGrdHeight As Single
  Dim sngCmdHeight As Single
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth
  sngHeight = ScaleHeight
  sngCmdHeight = 315
  sngGrdHeight = sngHeight - sngCmdHeight
  MSFlexGrid1.Move 0, 0, sngWidth, sngGrdHeight
  Command1.Move 0, sngGrdHeight, sngWidth, sngCmdHeight
End Sub
```